# How to select single row with max count using group by when multiple rows with same count exist

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a relatively simple table but am running into an issue on how to select distinct values with max count.

[image]

Above is an example of a single ID in the table (ID, VARIANT, Count). Do note that multiple IDs exist (so imagine 811, 812, etc. all with different 2 char values for VARIANT).

I need to select a **s%** and **n%** VARIANT (i.e. sb or s2 or s1) with the max count value. The problem is that I can't just group by VARIANT as I need to select both ID and VARIANT for joining to another table.

I.e. for example, one viable result from the picture above is row 1 and row 3 being returned, or row 1 and row 4, or row 2 and row 3.

What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry about that, it's oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, substr(variant, 1, 1) order by cnt desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```